# Add custom field data to map pop up

Tags: profile

We are looking to add the hours (a custom field) to the popup when locations are mapped. I am looking at the template here: templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Map. I'd like to replace the location type with the hours. I can remove the location type but cannot determine what to use to bring in the custom data. May not be possible without a bunch of customization. Any thoughts?

CiviCRM 4.7.27 & WordPress

Below is a screen shot. It is the page that comes up when you have search results from a profile search (public directory) and you click the link "map these contacts".

[image]

Comment: What screen is it exactly? What do you click on to get there? Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Just edited question and included screenshot.